# How to populate selectbox in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

This my json data how to set a selected option of a dropdown list control using angular JS

```
$scope.alltoys=[
       {
         "dId": "570b886545034f0001718247",
         "dName": "Toys",
         "dSubName": "Comics",
         "users": [
           {
                "name": "Superman",
                "id": "570b9e3a45034f000171827b"
           },
           {
                "name": "Batman",
                "id": "570ba00045034f000171828a"
           }]
       },
       {
        "dId": "5767c68c52faff0001fb8555",
        "dName": "Toys",
        "dSubName": "General",
        "users": [
           {
                "name": "Jack",
                "id": "570b9e3a45034f000171827b"
           },
           {
                "name": "Sparrow",
                "id": "570ba00045034f000171828a"
           }]
        }
]
```

How to populate this select box using angular js

I want to populate like this

```
Toys-Comics
    Batman
    Superman
Toys-General
    Jack
    Sparrow
```

In here Toys-Comics & Toys-General are only title of that selected content
I want to sort users array when populate.

```
<div class="controls">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="toy"
        ng-options="eachtoy as eachtoy.dName+' - '+eachtoy.dSubName group by eachtoy for eachtoy in alltoys">
        <option value="">---------------Select---------------</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I tried this but its not working.

Comment: tried with order by?

Comment: Use mdMenu rather than drop down

Comment: @Kiran Kumar I didnt understand.Can you help me ji.Could you understand my question?

Comment: @LonelyPlanet I tried but i didnt get it

Comment: your $scope.alltoys json is not correct.(not formatted)

Comment: @ManojLodhi why manoj its correct only rit i got result but its not in correct way what i am expected I need above i mentioned

Comment: Invalid json, please correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of changes.  First, make sure $scope.alltoys is a collection (array), like this:

```
$scope.alltoys = [{
  "dId": "570b886545034f0001718247",
  "dName": "Toys",
  "dSubName": "Comics",
  "users": [{
    "name": "Superman",
    "id": "570b9e3a45034f000171827b"
  }, {
    "name": "Batman",
    "id": "570ba00045034f000171828a"
  }]
}, {
  "dId": "5767c68c52faff0001fb8555",
  "dName": "Toys",
  "dSubName": "General",
  "users": [{
    "name": "Jack",
    "id": "570b9e3a45034f000171827b"
  }, {
    "name": "Sparrow",
    "id": "570ba00045034f000171828a"
  }]
}];
```

Then change your html to handle groups with optgroup, like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="toy">
  <option value="">---------------Select---------------</option>
  <optgroup ng-repeat="eachtoy in alltoys | orderBy: 'dName + dSubName" label="{{eachtoy.dName+' - '+eachtoy.dSubName}}">
    <option ng-repeat="user in eachtoy.users | orderBy: 'name'">{{user.name}}</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/94ShFFmXSQiiE9BfzqSv?p=preview)

Comment: how to sorted both heading and content is it posiible

Comment: Sure.  Use orderBy ... I've updated my answer and plunk

Comment: super brown very good your anser is awsome I am new in angular js. I think you are in swim in this good very good

Comment: You're welcome.  You put together a well written, concise question that made it easy to help you.  Nice job!  Good luck with Angular ... its a great framework.

Comment: how to get corresponding selected toys id i didnt get it?

Comment: Add the value attribute to your option tag, like this <option ng-repeat="user in eachtoy.users | orderBy: 'name'" value="{{user.id}}">  Then $scope.toy will be set to the id of the selected toy